# moving emails on cPanel or plesk to specific folder based on tag

Tags: spam, exim

I have hosting servers with cPanel and Plesk, which have more than 1000 customers. I want that when any email is marked as spam, then it should be moved automatically to JUNK folder, instead of customer moving it himself to specific junk folder. Just like Gmail spam , all spam goes to SPAM folder. can it be done on Server level ? as i know that use level filters are already available , but i want to implement it server-wide

Comment: What IMAP-server you have used?

Comment: Who is marking the emails as spam: the end user or a script?

Comment: spamassasin is marking, as i am using Dovecot

Comment: That sounds like you want a default rule created for all existing mailboxes and any new ones. Yes that's possible, the how depends on your filter you want to support: Sieve, procmail etc... Regardless, the abstraction levels control panels provide (and the resulting lack of details in your question) make it unlikely that ServerFault can provide you with a suitable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With dovecot's plugin `pidgeonhole` you can setup the `sieve` filter. But you have to ensure that exim used `dovecot-lda` aka `deliver` for local delivery. Look at your transports in exim's config. If there is `deliver` invoked - everything is simple enough.
Also check whether the `dovecot-pidgeonhole` is installed. If no - install it.

Add the next sections to the dovecot config (if they are not exist already):

```
. . . . .
protocols               = imap pop3 sieve
. . . . .
plugin {
. . . . .
  sieve_before          = /path/dovecot/common.sieve
}
. . . . .
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins          = sieve
}
. . . . .
```

Create file /path/dovecot/common.sieve :

```
####
require "fileinto";
if exists "X-Spam-Detected"
{ fileinto "Junk"; stop; }
else
{ keep; }
####
```

Replace `X-Spam-Detected` with header your spamassassin adds to the messages.

Launch `sievec /path/dovecot/common.sieve` to compile script to the binary. Change its ownership to the uid your dovecot used. Restart dovecot. That's all. Now all messages containing header `X-Spam-Detected` will be delivered to the `/var/vmail/domain/user/.Junk` or `~/user/Maildir/.Junk` - as configured in dovecot.